# Post scores to facebook without signed_request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed a flash game, which runs on a website and is not supposed to run directly on Facebook as iframe etc. I have registered an app with Facebook and have id and secret, have entered my app domain for auth and enabled highscore, but when following this tutorial:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/539/
I do not receive the signed_request.

Is it possible at all to post scores to Facebook profiles from an external game, or does the game have to run in facebook as iframe?

Comment: What tutorial are you following?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it doesn't have to run in the iFrame, but it does have to have a signed in user to post anything back to FB.

You need to have the signed_request in order to post any scores out to the high score

Comment: Hi, so do you know how to receive or whether it is even possible to receive the signed_request outside of the Facebook platform. It seems to me, as though the signed_request is only available to apps running in an iFrame on the Facebook platform?

Comment: You can embed the FB login code into your site using the JavaScript SDK.  As a part of that, you can get your authentication and signed_request object from the authentication calls.  

Check out the JavaScript SDK here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

And check out the Authentication calls here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Yes, you're going to have to create a facebook app that you can use to authenticate your web site with, and that's the IDs that you'll pass in to the javascript calls to FB.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Facebook Connect. Also Adobe has a sample workaround to connect properly: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/samples.html

(Edit) Also you can check out this API: http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input - I should have clarified though, that  I do not need to publish the scores from flash directly, but from php (Zend Framework), so I need a working solution in php that works outside of the facebook platform...

Comment: For PHP http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ , you can have a look how to initialize but keep in your mind, especially for wall posts, take user confirmation. To do that without navigating outside of Flash, you have to use Flash API. For a quick resolution, make a gateway php page with proper open graph meta tags, and open a popup for sharing with the confirmation via External.interface (Javascript) from Flash. Here is the url of Facebook sharer: http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[PAGEURL]